# Cannot find module 'findup-sync' when trying to run grunt

Tags: node.js, gruntjs

I am having trouble running `grunt-cli` after installing it. I run

```
npm install -g grunt-cli
```

then running grunt errors with

```
    node.js:63
    throw e;
    ^
Error: Cannot find module 'findup-sync'
    at loadModule (node.js:275:15)
    at require (node.js:411:14)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/tmartin/bin/grunt:9:14)
    at Module._compile (node.js:462:23)
    at Module._loadScriptSync (node.js:469:10)
    at Module.loadSync (node.js:338:12)
    at Object.runMain (node.js:522:24)
    at Array.<anonymous> (node.js:756:12)
    at EventEmitter._tickCallback (node.js:55:22)
    at node.js:773:9
```

This is what I have installed:

```
tmartin@timcomp:~$ npm list -g
/home/tmartin/lib
└─┬ grunt-cli@0.1.6
  ├─┬ findup-sync@0.1.2
  │ ├─┬ glob@3.1.21
  │ │ ├── graceful-fs@1.2.0
  │ │ ├── inherits@1.0.0
  │ │ └─┬ minimatch@0.2.11
  │ │   ├── lru-cache@2.2.2
  │ │   └── sigmund@1.0.0
  │ └── lodash@1.0.1
  └─┬ nopt@1.0.10
    └── abbrev@1.0.4
```

Comment: I had this problem because I installed grunt-cli and grunt like this `npm install -g grunt grunt-cli`.  Grunt-cli needs to be installed before grunt so it should be `npm install -g grunt-cli grunt`

Comment: I had a very similar error, and switching the order of npm install did it for me as well.

Answer (score 13):

I had to install and link findup-sync and a few other npm packages to get these dependency issues to go away.  I though npm was supposed to handle them for us, but installing the dependencies manually made the issues go away.

`npm install findup-sync -g`

`npm link findup-sync`

Comment: You'd think this would work based on the error, but in fact I already have the findup-sync files in the right place. I ran this again but still same error. FWIW I'm having this issue on OS X. Probably Node or Grunt distro bug.

Answer (score 13):

I got mine running again reinstalling grunt-cli globally and in my repo.

`npm install -g grunt-cli`

`cd myrepo`

`npm install grunt-cli`

I think Yosemite installation broke some things in my files ...

Comment: `yarn global add grunt-cli` for yarn users

Answer (score 6):

This is because npm doesn't set the right permission to sub-directory node_modules in /usr/lib/node_modules/grunt-cli.
In my case, I had:

```
drwxr-x--- 6 nobody root 4096 16 févr. 17:08 node_modules
```

When running grunt as non-root user, I had the same error (Cannot find module 'findup-sync') because of a permission denied to read this directory.

The solution is to fix permission with chmod: chmod a+rx node_modules.

But in fact, all directories was involved. The best way was to todo:

```
find /usr/lib/node_modules/grunt-cli -type d -exec chmod a+rx {} \;
```

This is maybe a distribution bug (I use Archlinux).

Answer (score 3):

This may seem simple, but if anyone else is unsure if there's a permissions problem, try running `sudo grunt` then go from there.

Answer (score 2):

I use NVM and was having this problem whenever I changed the active node version.

Following @davidcondrey 's suggestion worked for me. The catch really was to install grunt-cli *before* grunt. The order made a difference and fixed it.

```
npm i -g grunt-cli grunt
```

@inostia 's answer of using *sudo* to test the permissions was OK, but gave me quite a headache with file permissions, as all the grunt-processed files were inacessible by git later and broke my versioning.

Answer (score 1):

This also may be obvious, but in my case I had set up my npm path off my home directory (on a chromebook) and needed to add .node_modules to my .profile
`PATH=~./node_modules:$PATH`
Then run:
`source ~/.profile`

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix this by reinstalling Grunt using these commands:

```
sudo npm remove -g grunt-cli
sudo npm install -g grunt-cli
```

Comment: `sudo`?  sudo should not be needed

Answer (score 0):

This issue occurs if you change your `NodeJS` version.

After changing the node version, re installing `grunt` or `npm install` will resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Tried all the answers above and I could not get grunt to work without using sudo

Finally came across [this Wordpress article](https://joekuan.wordpress.com/2015/03/23/issue-on-running-grunt-error-cannot-find-module-findup-sync/) and deleted the link to `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/grunt/bin/grunt`

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 35 Apr 19 22:45 /usr/local/bin/grunt -> ../lib/node_modules/grunt/bin/grunt
```

using `sudo rm /usr/local/bin/grunt`

Then I linked to the grunt executable in /usr/local/lib/node_modules/grunt-cli/bin

using `sudo ln -s /usr/local/lib/node_modules/grunt-cli/bin/grunt /usr/local/bin/grunt`

Now, I can run grunt without using sudo

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by running:

```
npm install -gg grunt-cli --force
```